# Injeção de Dependência no .NET Core

Tags: c#, injeção-de-dependência, .net-core, asp.net-core

Estou migrando um projeto WebAPI com .NET Framework 4.6 para .NET Core.

Nesse meu projeto eu uso o Unity para fazer Injeção de Dependência:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
container.RegisterType<IUserService, UserService>();
```

No .NET Core não consegui utilizar o Unity da mesma forma que eu fazia no .NET 4.6 e achei uma solução para utilizar dessa forma, colocando no meu Startup.cs

```
// DI Containers Registration
services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
```

Qual seria a melhor prática hoje em .NET Core para Injeção de Dependência, vale a pena usar algum componente como StructureMap, CastleWindsor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após pesquisas encontrei um material interessante, segue exemplos:

Podemos injetar dependência no .NET Core da seguinte forma:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddSingleton<IRenderSingleton, RenderSingleton>();

    services.AddScoped<IRenderScoped, RenderScoped>();

    services.AddTransient<IRenderTransient, RenderTransient>();    
}
```

Nesse exemplo de código têm 3 tipos de ciclo de vida que podem ser utilizado:

- **Singleton** (que me garante um única referencia dessa classe no ciclo de vida de uma aplicação),
- **Transient** (sempre gerará uma nova instância para cada item encontrado que possua tal dependência, ou seja, se houver 5 dependências serão 5 instâncias diferentes) e
- **Scoped**(essa diferente da Transient que garante que em uma requisição seja criada um instância de um classe onde se houver outras dependências, seja utilizada essa única instância pra todas, renovando somente nas requisições subsequentes, mas, mantendo essa obrigatoriedade).